# BitBucket server Rest API call to get a list of merged pull requests between 2 tags

Tags: rest, bitbucket-server

I am trying to get a list of all merged pull requests on one branch between two tags using REST API calls on Bitbucket Server.

I did not find any documentation on the restricting list within a specific range

Is there a way to do it with GET rest api call below:

`/REST/API/1.0/PROJECTS/{PROJECTKEY}/REPOS/{REPOSITORYSLUG}/PULL-REQUESTS?DIRECTION&AT&STATE&ORDER&WITHATTRIBUTES&WITHPROPERTIES`